# MySQL - max( ) row values of subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, max

I have a table in which the rainfall is recorded every 15 minutes, so the total rainfall for a day is the sum of 'rain' in 95 records. The following query correctly returns a list of dates and the rainfall for that day.

```
select thedate as tdate,sum(rain) as dailyrain
from  weatherdata
group by year(thedate), month(thedate), day(thedate)
```

(thedate stored as datetime, rain stored as integer )

I now want to make this a sub query and return the date on which there was maximum rainfall.

My query below correctly returns the maximum rain amount, but not the correct date linked with that rainfall.

```
select maxdate,max(dailyrain) from (select thedate as maxdate,sum(rain) as dailyrain
from  weatherdata
group by year(thedate), month(thedate), day(thedate)) as maxrain
```

I think I probably have to use a JOIN. I know many similar questions have been answered here but I can't quite get the syntax right to make this work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can also change the group by to `GROUP BY DATE(thedate)`. It will be slightly more efficient.

Comment: No need for subselect here, just proper grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(thedate) as tdate, sum(rain) as dailyrain
FROM weatherdata
GROUP BY DATE(thedate)
ORDER BY sum(rain) DESC, DATE(thedate) DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

or:

```
SELECT DATE(thedate) as tdate, sum(rain) as dailyrain
FROM weatherdata
GROUP BY DATE(thedate)
ORDER BY dailyrain DESC, tdate DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: @eggyal thanks for the constructive tips. I think I've fixed it up now.

Comment: Yep.  Now in a tie the result is determinate, but will still be only a single (the most recent) record - which or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks but this gives a syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 thedate as tdate, sum(rain) as dailyrain ' at line 1

Comment: Aah -  the first version gave a syntax error but the edited version seems to give the right answer - thank you! Elegantly simple! Its only working with about 12 days data at the moment.

Comment: Yes - that definitely works. I suppose it would be neat if it returned all results in the case of a tie, but a tie is fairly unlikely as I'm recording fractions of a mm (I lied about the INT!) and I'm very happy with this. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

To get *all* dates having the maximal rainfall:

```
SELECT   DATE(thedate), SUM(rain)
FROM     weatherdata
GROUP BY DATE(thedate)
HAVING   SUM(rain) = (
           SELECT   SUM(rain)
           FROM     weatherdata
           GROUP BY DATE(thedate)
           ORDER BY SUM(rain) DESC
           LIMIT    1
         )
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. That returns all the days and daily rainfall in date order without selecting the max.

Comment: I see it does work in sql Fiddle - could be my testing server is using an old version of mySQL - I'll check it out tomorrow. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
select tdate,dailyrain from
   (select date(thedate) as tdate,sum(rain) as dailyrain
    from  weatherdata
    group by date(thedate))r
WHERE dailyrain =
                  (select max(dailyrain) as maxrain from
                      (select date(thedate) as tdate,sum(rain) as dailyrain
                       from  weatherdata
                       group by date(thedate)
                      )m
                   )
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e4c4/3/0)

Comment: Hi - thanks. This gives 'Unknown column 'rain' in 'field list''

Comment: do you have a column named rain? I thought you did, try the sqlFiddle.

Comment: Hi - yes - I do have a column named rain. This works fine in sqlFiddle but not on my project (using Coldfusion). Maybe that uses different rules?

Comment: strange i thought it's independent of programming language since it is run by the mySQL server.